# Is stat's st_blksize measured in bits or bytes?

Tags: c, posix, stat

I'm trying to find the block size on my machine using these lines:

```
struct stat fi;
stat("/tmp", &fi);
BLOCK_SIZE = fi.st_blksize;
```

Does BLOCK_SIZE represent the amount of **bytes** or the amount of **bits** in a single block?

The documentation says:

> "    blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */ "

Comment: It's in bytes, not in bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read [this POSIX `<sys/stat.h>` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) you will find

> The unit for the *`st_blocks`* member of the **`stat`** structure is not defined within POSIX.1-2008. In some implementations it is 512 bytes. It may differ on a file system basis. There is no correlation between values of the *`st_blocks`* and *`st_blksize`*, and the *`f_bsize`* (from [*`<sys/statvfs.h>`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_statvfs.h.html9) structure members.

So while there's no standardized unit for `st_blksize` it's unlikely that it's in bits. To get the actual unit you have to research the current operating system, and possibly even the filesystem used.

The [Linux `stat` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) doesn't mention the unit explicitly, but in [the example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html#EXAMPLE) it says the unit is in bytes.

Answer (score 3):

It is in `Bytes`. Refer the Linux man page example code [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html):-

`printf("Preferred I/O block size: %ld bytes\n", (long) sb.st_blksize);`

```
  The following program calls stat() and displays selected fields in
   the returned stat structure.

   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/sysmacros.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       struct stat sb;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (stat(argv[1], &sb) == -1) {
           perror("stat");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("ID of containing device:  [%lx,%lx]\n",
            (long) major(sb.st_dev), (long) minor(sb.st_dev));

       printf("File type: ");

       switch (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
       case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
       case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
       case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
       case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
       case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
       case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
       case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
       default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
       }

       printf("I-node number:            %ld\n", (long) sb.st_ino);

       printf("Mode:                     %lo (octal)\n",
               (unsigned long) sb.st_mode);

       printf("Link count:               %ld\n", (long) sb.st_nlink);
       printf("Ownership:                UID=%ld   GID=%ld\n",
               (long) sb.st_uid, (long) sb.st_gid);

       printf("Preferred I/O block size: %ld bytes\n",
               (long) sb.st_blksize);
       printf("File size:                %lld bytes\n",
               (long long) sb.st_size);
       printf("Blocks allocated:         %lld\n",
               (long long) sb.st_blocks);

       printf("Last status change:       %s", ctime(&sb.st_ctime));
       printf("Last file access:         %s", ctime(&sb.st_atime));
       printf("Last file modification:   %s", ctime(&sb.st_mtime));

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Block sizes are usually given in bytes and in the case of `stat` it is. Giving it in bits would not make much sense.